# Can I ask a question about achieving a specific effect in Photoshop?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

How do I get this effect in photoshop? (the hover effect on portfolio)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I would say yes, this should be allowed, **if** it is made to be more detailed and refer to a speficic detail of the process like "How do I achieve the white/green gradient effect with the slight shadow above it?" or "How do I add the shadow effect to the text"?

Comment: +1 because that is reason im here :)